# Android: Strike out line color

Tags: android

I've done strike out text using below code.

```
tvIngredient.setPaintFlags(tvIngredient.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

and cancel the strike out i've used below code

```
tvIngredient.setPaintFlags(tvIngredient.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
```

My question is , how to change the color of the strike out line.?

Comment: May I know where you use this?

Comment: Is `tvIngredient` is a `listview`?

Comment: no man. i'm using in listview adapter classs. its a  textview. holder.tvIngredient

Answer (score 1):

This will create a strike out line on your view

```
<View
      android:id="@+id/View_Strike"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_below="@id/Layout_myRow"
          android:layout_height="1dp"
          android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

Now where you are designing a **row layout** for your **listview**. place this above view in such a way that it overlaps you **Text View** at the desired position in you Row Layout

and set its `visibility Gone`

Now depending on the Situation when you have to strike thru Your Item make its Visibility Visible

Surely is the solution !! i have used it in one of my app

```
Just remember that the parent layout have to be **RelativeLayout** to use layout_below on child**
```

Answer (score 1):

use a layer-list and place it on top of the textview as a background.

create in the drawables folder a file called
strikethru.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#8d8d8d"/> <!-- adjust color you want here -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

then in your textview do this:

```
    <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_prod_price"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                                android:paddingRight="3dp"
                                android:text="1,290 B"      

android:background="@drawable/strikethru_line"
                                android:textColor="#070707"
                                android:textSize="13sp" />
```

the padding right of 3dp makes the strike through more evident.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can also create a custom textview and draw a line on textview canvas with paint of color and thickness of stroke you like

```
class CustomTextView extends TextView {
        public Paint paint;
        public boolean addStrike = false;

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (addStrike) {
            canvas.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(),
                    getHeight() / 2, paint);
        }
    }

}
```

Also for adding stoke you can call

```
myCustomTextView.addStrike = true;
myCustomTextView.invalidate();
```

and for removing strike you just call

```
myCustomTextView.addStrike = false;
myCustomTextView.invalidate();
```